# How would I go about making device drivers for my own kernel?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, driver, hardware, device-driver

I am making my own operating system for fun. I'm reading and learning a lot from the Intel's 64bit and IA-32 architecture manual which is helpful for developing an operating system.

But one thing that I just can't find anywhere is how to make device drivers. The only posts I can find about device drivers on the internet are about making Linux or Windows drivers. But it's different from making drivers for *my own* kernel.

Can someone experienced please point me into the right direction, enlighten me *where* I can learn making my own device drivers for my own operating system?

For a start, simple keyboard or mouse drivers are enough, but I will appreciate anything, be it simple keyboard drivers, or complex network drivers

**TL;DR:** I need a solid source explaining how to make device drivers for my own kernel. I can't find any and hope that someone have stumbled upon one

(I'm not asking "how to make drivers?", but rather asking "can I have links to books/posts about making drivers?")

Comment: Off-topic since too broad. You first need to read a good book, like [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and then you need to understand the details of your hardware (including bus controllers and IO devices!), see [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/) wiki

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch maybe I wrote it a little differwntly than I wanted it to come out. My question isn't "how to" but "can you point me to a resource saying how to". It's not broad at all in my opinion :)

Comment: You certainly should **edit your question** to add more stuff in it (to make it less broad). Asking for resources is off-topic on StackOverflow. However, you should look into http://osdev.org/ and you'll better study in details *existing* free software implementations, such as the Linux kernel. Hint: it is much harder than what you imagine. BTW consider publishing your toy kernel source as free software, e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) or elsewhere

Comment: "Can I have links about making drivers" is off-topic, but start first with OSDEV then study the source code in Linux (there are many books explaining it) or in some other free software OS (like FreeBSD)

Comment: I certainly will make a github repo. And yes, osdev is a good resource about making operating systems, but still couldn't find anything about drivers :(

Comment: Then you did not read OSDEV well enough. The information is there. Of course you need before that to spend weeks reading about OSes. So stop coding for a few days and read the references I have gave you

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I guess I didn't dig too deep then, thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

All a kernel-mode device driver is, is code executing under the kernel, which is not treated as the "main" kernel image itself - consider it as an "extension" to the main kernel image. On Windows for example, kernel-mode device drivers (which tend to use the *.sys file extension, which is also belonging to the Portable Executable (PE) Format) are treated as modules to ntoskrnl.exe (which is the main kernel image on Windows).

The idea is that your kernel-mode device drivers will have access to routines exported by your main kernel image (e.g. if you want to implement mechanisms like kernel-mode callbacks). You could start by making your own simple format for your kernel to understand, and then you can start implementing export support appropriate for your own file format (for the main kernel image) and import support (for the other kernel-mode software to make use of the APIs which it should have access to, provided by the main kernel image).

You'll have a lot of work to do if you want a good design implementation.